# How to add css class to image attached in all the posts?

Tags: functions, theme-development, images

Currently by default image have similar classes

```
<img class="size-full wp-image-8996" src="https://nepaltimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/31043884_1792179470828697_8330507756888915968_n.jpg">
```

**What i am trying here to add a class as img-fluid to all the attachments in posts not the thumbnails.**

```
<img class="img-fluid size-full wp-image-8996" src="https://nepaltimes.net/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/31043884_1792179470828697_8330507756888915968_n.jpg">
```

How could it be done?
Any Idea will be appreciated!
Please help me

Comment: Are you using a function to display image?  Like the_post_thumbnail() ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the filter [`get_image_tag_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_image_tag_class/) which exists exactly to do what you want:

```
add_filter('get_image_tag_class','wpse302130_add_image_class');

function wpse302130_add_image_class ($class){
    $class .= ' img-fluid';
    return $class;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry i added it in functions.php but it didn't work   https://goo.gl/r4eK21   Please help me

Comment: It will not work on existing posts.

Comment: And it will not work for ```the_post_thumbnail();```.
It will work only for what you have in wysiwyg editor

Comment: Also will not work if you generate posts programatically, or with a plugin like Faker Press

Answer (score 0):

cjbj's answer seems more better but i am still leaving this for reference that we can also do these ways.

There are 3 way.

1. Solve it in frontend(with Javascript)
2. Solve it in backend(with PHP)
3. Solve it manually

First one, you run javascript to add class like:

ref.: [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)

```
function myFunction() {
  var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  element.classList.add("mystyle");
}
```

while you loop through all the img tags.

Second one, you have to parse post contents with PHP DOM and do the same thing like Javascript.

Third one, you edit the post with text and add your class manually.

Comment: I tried using the javascript, it don't execute though, Please show me a proper path to implement it successfully! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

These above solutions are great but for an incredibly simple fix for this specific issue. I've added the CSS for img-fluid onto the standard classes that wordpress adds to it's images:

```
.size-thumbnail, .size-medium, .size-large, .size-full {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

This may not be as elegant as the above solutions but performance wise it's just a little chunk of CSS.